# Assign vector component using string in R

Tags: r, parsing, variable-assignment, stan, rstan

I have a string, say `"ti[123]"`, and a corresponding value, say `1.2`
What is the command I should use in R to assign `1.2` to the 123rd position of vector `ti` ?
I tried `assign("ti[123]",1.2)` but it creates a new variable with name `ti[123]`, which is not what I expected.

The reason I need to do this is that I use rstan's `optimizing` function to optimize a model, and it returns a named vector, with names like this (if you happen to use vectors of parameters in your model).

Comment: How about `replace(ti, 123, 1.2)`? That will replace 123 with 1.2.

Comment: If you need to extract from the string `library(stringr); assign('ti', '[[<-'(ti, as.numeric(str_extract("ti[123]", '(?<=\\[)\\d+')), 1.2))`

Comment: I bet there's a better way to extract the results from the stan output ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can extract the number from the string using `str_extract` and `assign` the value

```
library(stringr)
assign('ti', '[[<-'(ti, as.numeric(str_extract("ti[123]",
                  '(?<=\\[)\\d+')), 1.2))
```

Or

```
ti[as.numeric(str_extract("ti[123]", '(?<=\\[)\\d+'))] <- 1.2
```

Another option would be `rm_square` from `library(qdapRegex)` to extract the numbers

```
library(qdapRegex) 
ti[as.numeric(rm_square('ti[123]', extract=TRUE))] <- 1.2
```

#### Update

If we don't know the object name,

```
str1 <- 'ti[123]'
v1 <- strsplit(str1, '[][]')[[1]]
assign(v1[1], `[[<-`(get(v1[1]), as.numeric(v1[2]), 1.2))
get(v1[1])[123]
#[1] 1.2
```

Or

```
ti[123]
#[1] 1.2
```

Comment: still doesn't work as you have `ti` show up as a variable, and I have no way of knowing whether it's going to be `ti` or another variable. It all has to be extracted from the string.

Comment: @yannick Updated the post.  Please check if that helps

Comment: I will mark this (very complicated) answer as correct, because `rstan` does not provide a simpler way it seems.

Answer (score 0):

`replace(ti, 123, 1.2)` probably will do the trick.

Comment: Yes, but how do you do the string parsing?